# How do I improve this Haskell function to evaluate an RPN expression?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Here's what I came up with:

```
solveRPNWrapper :: (Read a, Integral a) => String -> a
solveRPNWrapper str = solveRPN [] $ words str

calcFunction :: String -> String -> String -> String
calcFunction "+" x y = show $ read x + read y
calcFunction "-" x y = show $ read x - read y
calcFunction "*" x y = show $ read x * read y
calcFunction "/" x y = show $ read x / read y
calcFunction op x y = error $ "Unknown operator: " ++ op ++ "."

isOperator :: String -> Bool
isOperator "+" = True
isOperator "-" = True
isOperator "*" = True
isOperator "/" = True
isOperator _ = False

solveRPN :: (Read a, Integral a) => [String] -> [String] -> a
solveRPN [] (x:[]) = read x
solveRPN [] (x:y:xs) = solveRPN (x:y:[]) xs
solveRPN stack (x:xs)
         | isOperator x =
           let z = calcFunction x (last (init stack)) (last stack)
           in solveRPN (init (init stack)) (z:xs)
         | otherwise = solveRPN (stack ++ [x]) xs
solveRPN stack [] = error $ "Badly formatted expression: Stack contains " ++ show stack
```

While it does work ...

```
*Main>  solveRPNWrapper "10 4 3 + 2 *  -"
-4
```

... I can see this is anything but idiomatic (surely lots of duplication in the operator bit and the read/show seems redundant), and the constraints might be messed up too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Change the type of the stack to `Integral a => [a]`. This not only removes the need for `read` and `show` everywhere, but also reveals a hidden type error in your original code. You were using fractional division (`/`) instead of integer division (`div`).
2. Reverse the stack. Lists are easier to manipulate from the front, so use that as the top of your stack. This also lets us use pattern matching on the stack to pick elements from the top of the stack easily instead of messing around with `last` and `init`. This is also more efficient.
3. Use a lookup table for the operators. This cuts down further on the duplication, and we can just store the corresponding Haskell functions (`+`, `div`, etc.) directly in the table.

This is what I ended up with after making those changes:

```
solveRPNWrapper :: (Read a, Integral a) => String -> a
solveRPNWrapper str = solveRPN [] $ words str

solveRPN :: (Read a, Integral a) => [a] -> [String] -> a
solveRPN [result] [] = result
solveRPN (y : x : stack) (token : tokens)
  | Just f <- lookup token operators = solveRPN (f x y : stack) tokens
solveRPN stack (token : tokens) = solveRPN (read token : stack) tokens
solveRPN stack [] = error $ "Badly formatted expression: Stack contains " ++ show (reverse stack)

operators :: Integral a => [(String, a -> a -> a)]
operators = [("+", (+)), ("-", (-)), ("*", (*)), ("/", div)]
```

You could also use a fold instead of recursion, but that would require adding some more error handling to the wrapper. I'd also consider using just `Integer` instead of `Integral a => a`, but that's just a matter of changing the type signatures.

For robustness, it would also probably be a good idea to use a pure form of error handling like `Either` or `Maybe` instead of using `error`, and use `reads` instead of `read` to handle malformed input.

Comment: Thanks ... just reversing the list and avoiding the read/show stuff seems to cut down most of the ugliness in my version!

Answer (score 6):

The others already told you almost everything in order to improve your code. I just wanted to add that there exists a very nicely written chapter in the book *Learn You a Haskell*, [Functioanlly Solving Problems](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functionally-solving-problems), whose first section explains exactly how to write a basic Reverse Nolish notation calculator by using `foldl`.

Comment: Wow this foldl version is embarrassingly elegant.

Answer (score 5):

If you define

```
data Token a = Literal a
             | Operator (a -> a -> a)
```

write a suitable

```
parseToken :: String -> Token a
```

and rewrite `solveRPN` to use this signature

```
solveRPN :: [a] -> [Token a] -> a
```

then `isOperator` and `calcFunction` become somewhat trivial, and you can avoid all that tedious `read`ing and `show`ing.

But, you'll have to stop fudging the division issue: `/` is only for `Fractional` (not `Integral`) types. You've been getting away with it so far because you're converting from and to strings every time, so the numbers have been converted to a fractional type when you've been doing division. You'll have to decide whether you want to use `div` or `quot` instead, or whether you want to use a fractional type.

(Also, the results of `parseToken` and `solveRPN` should be wrapped inside `Maybe` (or an `Either` type) so you can indicate failure with `Nothing` instead of throwing an exception.)

Answer (score 3):

### Use lists efficiently (easy)

A simple method of making it more idiomatic is to reverse `stack` (this makes it a little more like a true stack), which allows you to use pattern matching and makes the code more efficient since attaching/reading at the head of list is an `O(1)` operation, while doing so at the end is `O(n)` i.e.:

```
solveRPN :: (Read a, Integral a) => [String] -> [String] -> a
solveRPN [] (x:[]) = read x
solveRPN [] (x:y:xs) = solveRPN (y:x:[]) xs -- push them on backwards
solveRPN stack@(s1:s2:rest) (x:xs) -- pattern match on stack with length >= 2
         | isOperator x =
           let z = calcFunction x s2 s1
           in solveRPN rest (z:xs)
         | otherwise = solveRPN (x:stack) xs
solveRPN stack (x:xs) -- last case: list with a single element
         | isOperator x = error "Stack too small"
         | otherwise = solveRPN (x:stack) xs
```

### Use the typesystem (important!)

You are using strings to encapsulate the two possible types on the input stack: operations and numbers, which allows for invalid input, idiomatic Haskell will leverage the type system so that a function always has a defined result (i.e. so that all functions are total).

It better is to use an ADT (algebraic data type) to encapsulate the possible operations and `Either` to distinguish between operations and literals in a type-safe way:

```
data Operation = Plus | Minus | Times | Divide

-- conversion function
readStackVar :: (Read a) => String -> Either Operation a
readStackVar "+" = Left Plus
readStackVar "-" = Left Minux
readStackVar "*" = Left Times
readStackVar "/" = Left Divide
readStackVar other = Right . read $ other
```

This allows you to write `isOperator` nicely (although it's actually unnecessary now):

```
isOperator :: Either Operation a -> Bool
isOperator (Left _) = False
isOperator _ = True
```

`calcFunction` is now typesafe (note the type doesn't have the `Either`) and there is no possibility of an unrecognised operation:

```
calcFunction :: (Integral a) => Operation -> a -> a -> a
calcFunction Plus = (+)
calcFunction Minus = (-)
calcFunction Times = (*)
calcFunction Divide = div -- integral division
```

Using these we can rewrite `solveRPN` (notice that we've avoided having to pass an empty list to `solveRPN`  by using the where clause):

```
solveRPN :: (Read a, Integral a) => [Either Operation a] -> a
solveRPN xs = go [] xs
   where
     go :: (Read a, Integral a) => [a] -> [Either Operation a] -> a
     go [] [] = error "Empty"
     go (x:xs) [] = x -- finished all the input
     go [] (x:y:xs) = go (y:x:[]) xs -- start the stack in reverse order

     go (s1:s2:rest) ((Left op):xs) = go ((calcFunction op s1 s2) : rest) xs -- operation   
     go stack ((Right x):xs) = go (x:stack) xs -- literal
```

Notice that I've been able to use pattern matching on the `Left` and `Right` of `Either` to distinguish between operations and literals. (An additional thing we could (and should) do is make `solveRPN` return `Maybe a` so that errors can be indicated by returning `Nothing` and success by returning `Just x`.)

This is used like:

```
solveRPN . map readStackVar . words $ "1 2 + 3 *"
```

(Warning: I haven't actually tested this, so there may be typos and small logic errors)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map` or just key-value pairs to store your operations:

```
ops = [("+",(+)),("-",(-)),("/",(/)),("*",(*))]

calcFunction :: String -> String -> String -> String
calcFunction op x y = go $ lookup op ops where
  go (Just f) = show $ read x `f` read y
  go Nothing = error $ "Unknown operator: " ++ op ++ "."

isOperator :: String -> Bool
isOperator op = elem op $ fst $ unzip ops
```